# Generating random vectors of Euclidean norm <= 1 in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, random

More specifically, given a natural number d, how can I generate random vectors in R^d such that each vector x has Euclidean norm <= 1?

Generating random vectors via numpy.random.rand(1,d) is no problem, but the likelihood of such a random vector having norm <= 1 is predictably bad for even not-small d. For example, even for d = 10 about 0.2% percent of such random vectors have appropriately small norm. So that seems like a silly solution.

EDIT: Re: Walter's comment, yes, I'm looking for a uniform distribution over vectors in the unit ball in R^d.

Comment: You should also define what probability distribution you expect. Uniform in euclidean space, I guess.

Comment: You can reduce the space for the subsequent numbers based on the constraints. For the most basic case, if d=2, and the first number is 0.4, generate the second in the interval [0, sqrt(1-0.4**2)]?

Comment: @ayhan: wouldn't this make it very unlikely for the last few dimensions to be high numbers (as this would require all previously dimensions being small), thus hurting randomness?

Comment: "nearly all of the high-dimensional space is "far away" from the centre. To put it another way, the high-dimensional unit hypercube can be said to consist almost entirely of the "corners" of the hypercube, with almost no "middle"" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality

Comment: @lamb_da_calculus You're right, the first number should't come from a uniform distribution.

Comment: I implemented the answer of @user2357112 in my answer, but don't want to steal the credit it deserves. If you are satisfied with both, accept that one, because mine is a mere implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the Wolfram Mathworld article on [hypersphere point picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html) and [Nate Eldredge's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/picking-random-points-in-the-volume-of-sphere-with-uniform-probability) to a similar question on math.stackexchange.com, you can generate such a vector by generating a vector of `d` independent Gaussian random variables and a random number `U` uniformly distributed over the closed interval `[0, 1]`, then normalizing the vector to norm `U^(1/d)`.

Comment: @WalterTross: Indeed, which is why we have the second step to fix the norm.

Comment: This seems slightly wrong. The question asks for the Euclidian norm, so normalisation should be to ```U**(1/2)```.

Comment: @C.Koca: That would only be correct for dimension d=2.

Comment: Consider what happens in the d=1 case. In that case, we're picking a point uniformly distributed over the interval `[-1, 1]`, so the norm should be uniformly distributed over `[0, 1]`. Normalizing to norm `U^(1/d)` gives us that, but taking a square root with `U^(1/2)` does not.

Comment: [Euclidian norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) is defined with 2.

Comment: @C.Koca: That's not what the `1/d` is for. When computing the Euclidean norm, we will of course compute it by squaring, summing, and taking the square root, rather than by using a dimension-dependent exponent. However, we will normalize the vector so that the result of squaring its elements, summing, and taking the square root is equal to `U^(1/d)`.

Comment: As mentioned in Walter Tross's answer, the uniform distribution in a d-dimensional unit sphere has cumulative radial distribution r^d, and generating a norm as `U^(1/d)` for `U` uniformly distributed over `[0, 1]` is a means of [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) from the correct distribution.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. You are normalising the length of the vector, ```U```, with ```(1/d)``` as you should. But You never normalise the gaussian variables. I thought that was where you normalised the ```d``` independent gaussian variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249046/discussion-between-c-koca-and-user2357112).

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer by user2357112, you need something like this:

```
import numpy as np
...
inv_d = 1.0 / d
for ...:
    gauss = np.random.normal(size=d)
    length = np.linalg.norm(gauss)
    if length == 0.0:
        x = gauss
    else:
        r = np.random.rand() ** inv_d
        x = np.multiply(gauss, r / length)
        # conceptually: / length followed by * r
    # do something with x
```

(this is my second Python program, so don't shoot at me...)

The tricks are that

- the combination of d independent gaussian variables with same σ is a gaussian distribution in d dimensions, which, remarkably, has spherical symmetry,
- the gaussian distribution in d dimensions can be projected onto the unit sphere by dividing by the norm, and
- the uniform distribution in a d-dimensional unit sphere has cumulative radial distribution r<sup>d</sup> (which is what you [need to invert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling))

Answer (score -1):

this is the Python / Numpy code I am using. Since it does not use loops, is much faster:

```
n_vectors=1000
d=2

rnd_vec=np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(n_vectors, d))                # the initial random vectors
unif=np.random.uniform(size=n_vectors)                               # a second array random numbers
scale_f=np.expand_dims(np.linalg.norm(rnd_vec, axis=1)/unif, axis=1) # the scaling factors
rnd_vec=rnd_vec/scale_f                                              # the random vectors in R^d
```

The second array of random numbers (*unif*) is needed as second scaling factor because otherwise all the vectors will have euclidean norm equal to one.

Comment: This produces a nonuniform distribution.